# React + Firebase - Can't read database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, react-hooks

Rewriting my project with React hooks instead of class components.

`myfile.js`

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const MessageList = () => {

 const [messages, setMessages]   = useState([]);
 const [usernames, setUsernames] = useState('');
 const [contents, setContents]   = useState('');
 const [roomId, setRoomId]       = useState('');

MessageList.messagesRef = MessageList.firebase.database().ref('messages');

useEffect(() => {

  MessageList.messagesRef.on('child added', snapshot => {

  const message = snapshot.val();

  message.key = snapshot.key;

  setMessages([...messages, message]);
 });
}, []);
```

I am getting `module not found: cannot resolve...` error and it's most likely because I don't know how to import my main `App.js` file.

If I have `src/components/myfile.js`, how would I add in an import statement in my `myfile.js` to reference the `App.js` file which is in my `src` folder?

I'm not sure if this is my only issue as I was running into other errors before.

**CURRENT ISSUE**

I have connected my firebase correctly, I believe, and am getting `cannot read property database of undefined` on this line:

`MessageList.messagesRef = MessageList.firebase.database().ref('messages');`

Comment: You can import App.js in myfile.js like `import App from '../App.js'`

Comment: thanks, now i have a parsing error `unexpected token, expected ";"` and it's pointing to the first bracket `{` of a function declaration I made called `handleChange(event)` right below the `useEffect` method, not inside.

Comment: Can you share the full code?

Comment: that issue has been resolved, it's now the **current issue**